# How were the names on the memorial stones in Avengers: Endgame chosen, out-of-universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, when

> Scott Lang escapes the Quantum Realm, one of the first places he passes by is the memorial park in San Francisco called **[Wall of the Vanished](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_the_Vanished)**.

There he finds several stones engraved with the names of thousands of people. The in-universe reason is quite straightforward. These were the names of

> all the people who became victims of the Decimation (Thanos' snap) with some of the known names (seen on-screen) from the memorial listed [here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_the_Vanished#San_Francisco_Memorial).

Is there an out-of-universe explanation about the names on the engraved stones? (For example, are these names of the people, in real life, related to the MCU or some sort of Easter Eggs to characters played by the actors of *Avengers: Endgame* in other movies?)

Comment: Technically, the “snappening” is not a decimation, which would be the killing of 1/10 of the population. I don’t think there is a proper word for it in a English, but if it existed, it would probably be “hemiation”.

Comment: I propose halvination!

Comment: @EuroMicelli, `demimation`

Comment: How about “***dusting-half-the-universe-with-a-snap-inator***”

Comment: "decimation" is derived from "deci-", which means one tenth in Latin. One half would be "semi-" or "demi-". Therefore, I believe "demination" would be the proper term for destroying one half of something.

Comment: @Shreedhar Hey, where's Perry?

Comment: @EuroMicelli It's a good thing most people don't speak technically, then! Decimate has been used to mean "kill a large portion of" for a _long_ time now. It's okay to use. Really, it is. There is no need to be pedantic. Language is defined by usage.

Comment: I prefer Salvation!

Comment: The Great Divorce?  Half of them are gone.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Book My Show reported that one of the names was Roberto da Costa aka Sunspot so there are at least *some* Easter Eggs hidden in the wall. Unfortunately they don't provide a visual of the name.

> MCU has always avoided referencing X-Men which might have been due to the fact that the rights were owned by Fox. Now that the Disney-Fox merger is over, we can expect to see more X-Men references, with Avengers: Endgame being the first of many. After Ant-Man returns from the quantum realm five years later, he comes across the Vanishing Memorial that has been set up with names of everyone who had been dusted and scans through them. One of the names is Roberto da Costa aka Sunspot, a mutant who is associated with The New Mutants and X-Force. He is confirmed to be in the New Mutants film coming this August and might be in the upcoming X-Force film with Deadpool too.
>
> <sub>[Book My Show, 7 EASTER EGGS YOU MAY HAVE MISSED IN AVENGERS: ENDGAME [SPOILER ALERT]](https://in.bookmyshow.com/entertainment/movies/english/avengers-endgame-easter-eggs/)</sub>

[Screen Rant reported on this](https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-vanished-list-names-marvel-movie-tribute/) as well taking their information from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/bhquvi/the_official_avengers_endgame_easter_egg/elvcobv/). Apparently some of the names belong to staff who have worked on Marvel movies.

> So between the names Scott goes through to (not) find his daughter's, there's a bunch of names that belong to people who worked on one or more Marvel movies in the past (or future), I looked through them and I'm gonna list them here now
>
> - Alistair Darby: VFX artist in Infinity War, you can find his name in the list under Online Press in the link.
> - Emily Denker: VFX editor in Ant-Man, Civil War, Doctor Strange, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Erika Denton: Clearance executive in everything past Iron Man 2 (included)
> - Paul Detlefston: Set dresser in Iron Man, Ant-Man, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Eric DeYoung: Propmaker in Iron Man 3
> - Geoff Diamond: CG artist in Infinity War
> - Paz Drimer: Digital production administrator in Homecoming, Infinity War, Ant-Man and the Wasp, Captain Marvel and Endgame
> - Giorgio Lafrata, most likely a mispelt attempt at Giorgio Lafratta: Hair/fur groomer in Homecoming, Ragnarok, Infinity War, Captain Marvel and Endgame
> - LaGraff, possibly Daniella LaGraff: 2nd assistant accountant in Homecoming, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Mårten Larsson: Associate VFX supervisor in Infinity War
> - Marco La Torre: Animator in Iron Man 2, Homecoming, Ragnarok, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Charlotte Lee: Set decoration buyer in Homecoming, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Talia Leone: Payroll accountant in Thor, The Winter Soldier, Ant-Man, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Sungmin Lim: Integration artist in Homecoming, Infinity War and Endgame
> - Mary Livanos: Manager of production and development of Guardians of The Galaxy Vol.2, associate producer of Captain Marvel and co-producer of Guardians of the Galaxy Vol.3
> - Lara Lom: VFX coordinator in Guardians of the Galaxy, VFX producer in Infinity War and Endgame
> - Hannah Long: VFX editor in at least Endgame
> - Susana Lou: Digital asset coordinator in Homecoming, Infinity War, Captain Marvel and Endgame (and also S1 of Daredevil and Jessica Jones)

Comment: Great find, great answer!

Comment: The list would have been most appropriate if the names were of those who had a 5-year hiatus working on MCU properties.